# same type of value in a single row using case or decode

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Dear friend I have written following query, and I got a result also as in image.

```
Select    
    (case when croptype_code < 13 then 'Pedi' else 'Paudha' end) pl_rpflag,
    nvl(sum(gh_area),0) as Area
    from w_cane_survey_2013
    where unit_code = '03' and gh_vill = '9991' and gh_grow= '1'
    group by croptype_code;
```

[image: Query result]

row1 and row3 both has **Paudha** but its area is displayed separately. Now I want that such values should be add. means all values of **Paudha** should be in a single row and all **Pedi** values in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT M.pl_rpflag, Sum(M.Area) FROM 
(
  SELECT (CASE WHEN croptype_code < 13 THEN 'Pedi' ELSE 'Paudha' end) AS pl_rpflag,
    nvl(sum(gh_area),0) AS Area
  FROM w_cane_survey_2013
  WHERE unit_code = '03' 
    AND gh_vill = '9991' 
    AND gh_grow= '1'
) AS M
GROUP BY M.pl_rpflag
```

Comment: `SELECT M.pl_rpflag, Sum(M.Area) FROM 
(
  SELECT (CASE WHEN croptype_code < 13 THEN 'Pedi' ELSE 'Paudha' end) AS pl_rpflag,
    nvl(sum(gh_area),0) AS Area
  FROM w_cane_survey_2013
  WHERE unit_code = '03' 
    AND gh_vill = '9991' 
    AND gh_grow= '1'
    group by croptype_code
) M
GROUP BY M.pl_rpflag;`


you forgot to put **group by** in subquery
'group by croptype_code'

Comment: I don't believe the group by is necessary in the sub query.

Comment: I executed that query without group by in sub-query and got an error message **ORA-00937: not a single-group group function**
Then I used **group by** in sub query and it worked